# Frames en ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, html5, css, ionic

Estoy tratando de implementar frames en mi aplicación ionic, lo que deseo es mostrar en la parte superior datos o información de un usuario y en la parte restante mostrar una pagina que consume webservices. (en este caso si no hay Internet,  se presentará un msj de error de conexión)

esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">
  <ion-content class="padding fondo">
    <FRAMESET rows="80,*">
        <frame name="central" src="perfil.html">
        <frame name="alto" src="paginaWeb.html">
    </FRAMESET>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

¿Como podría implementar? ya que al momento de ejecutar no me muestra nada. De antemano les agradezco mucho

Pta. La idea es que, así no haya conexión a internet se muestre la informacion del usuario y en el otro frame mi mensaje de error.

para que me puedan entender comparto este enlace [frames html](http://www.htmlpoint.com/guida/html_13.htm)

Comment: Los `frames` y `framesets` están obsoletos. Deberías usar `iframe` en su lugar

Answer (score 1):

Bueno se exactamente lo que quieres hacer, pero no entiendo muy bien el código que esta arriba, ya que tienes el llamado de la librería `css` de **ionic** y debajo tu código, no veo ni el `head` completo ni el `body`, de igual forma te voy a dar la solución a eso que quieres.

#### Almacenamiento local

Existen dos formas si utilizas ionic, puedes utilizar localstorage o SQLite, ambos tienen sus plugins para usarlo en ionic con cordova, [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/).

#### verificación de conexión

También en los plugins de ngCordova puedes encontrar uno para utilizarlo de forma nativa, o puedes recurrir a javascript nativo para saber si tu dispositivo esta conectado o no a internet.

Comment: Lo unico que deseo saber es como agregar frames a una vista amigo. osea separar vistas en una sola pantalla lo de ngcordova si tengo

Comment: @DiegoIsraelMoreno segun te estoy entendiendo quieres meter varios ficheros html en una misma vista, sinceramente no se si eos se pueda, mas si quieres separar en uns misma pantalla poner varios resultados ya eso depende de lo que quieras hacer, por que ***frames***, hasta donde se, hace referencia a cada recuadro de un video

Comment: si eso es lo que quiero. he visto que si hay como hacer pero con ionic nose esa es mi duda

Comment: @DiegoIsraelMoreno muéstrame un ejemplo, copia aquí algún enlace para entender mejor, creo saber pero quiero estar seguro, edita tu pregunta y coloca alguna imagen de algun ejemplo

Comment: he agregado un link espero te pueda servir

Comment: @DiegoIsraelMoreno ya vi el enlace, no conocía ese atributo. Nunca lo he usado, asi que no entiendo la razon de su uso, pero deduzco que lo que quieres es separar, de forma constante el contenido de la pantalla cuando se abra la aplicacion.

Comment: si, asi tal cual los ejemplos de ese link. el cual usa frame para mostrar diferentes vistas html

Comment: @DiegoIsraelMoreno no se de verdad si para eso es el uso de esa etiqueta, pero si lo qu quieres es dividir con simetria y todo eso y que siempre sea responsive, echale un ojo a flexbox

Comment: listo eso hare y gracias por sus comentarios

Comment: @DiegoIsraelMoreno echate una pasada por el [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol), pues ahora se puede decir que no hay actividad pero de dia si